# Laravel ErrorException Undefined variable $product

Tags: laravel

i have littel problem in my code, i dont know write mastake but i check my code is good

This ShopController
`

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
        return view('shop.show');
    }
```

`

this my route

`

```
Route::get('/shop/detail/{id}', 'ShopController@show');
```

`

this my view

`

```
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="title">{{$product->name}}</h2>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="col-lg-4" id="picture">
      <img src="{{asset($product->image)}}" alt="" height="200" width="200">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 desc">
      <h4 id="description">Description</h4>
      <p>{{$product->desc}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="kartu">
        <p>Harga</p>
        <h2>Rp {{number_format($product->price)}}</h2>
        <form action="" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="item_id">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add to Cart">
    </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

I have checked my code and there are no errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't pass the product to the view. You need to compact the variable like this in the controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
    return view('shop.show', compact('product'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting product from database in **$product** variable, but not passing that variable to your view. There are several ways to pass variables to view.

```
return view('shop.show', compact('product'));
```

OR

```
return view('shop.show', ['product' => $product]);
```

OR

```
return view('shop.show', get_defined_vars());
```

get_defined_vars() is built-in php function, by using this function any numbers of variables declared in method, all will be passed to view